# Cost of multiplication when e is randomly selected. RSA

Tags: rsa

Using schoolbook multiplication (which has cost $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$) to multiply two $n$-bit numbers)

- what is the cost of computing an RSA encryption with $e = 3$?
- What is the cost if $e$ is chosen randomly in the range $\{3, 5, 7, \ldots, \varphi(N) − 1\}$?

Comment: I've given hints so you can learn. Post your calculations here on the comment so we can check them.

Comment: It was a midterm review. Thanks but it might be a little bit till I come back to this lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is schoolbook multiplication and homework, I'll give some hints.

Note that, your question is missing an important part, which algorithm we use in the modular exponentiation?

- We don't have just multiplications due to the exponentiation operation. We also need the modular reduction. See [Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) for general detail.

$$ m^e = c \bmod n$$

- You may apply either taking the exponentiation than modular reduction, which will cause huge intermediate values, or you can use apply multiple and reduction paradigm. For this in general, [Exponentiating by Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)  algorithm is used.
- Now, reduction, in this case, requires modular reduction that. You may or may not add this into your calculations.
- for the second part, **hint**; when using the Exponentiating by Squaring we use the bits of the exponent.